# How can I generate a password in the app language

Tags: ios, swift, localization, generator, locale

I would like to get all of the characters that the user's current keyboard language is using for the app so I can generate a password.  This is not for a login or website. I don't want to hand code each language text string for every possible language.

```
@objc func didPressGeneratorPasswordButton(button: UIButton) {

    let locale = NSLocale.current.languageCode
    let english = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%^&*?"
    let korean = "????????"
    var textString = ""


    if locale == "en" {
        textString = english // Remove the english variable and replace with language keyboard characters.
    }else if locale == "ko" {
        textString = korean // Remove the korean variable and replace with language keyboard characters.
    }

    let len = 15
    let pswdChars = "\(textString)"
    let rndPswd = String((0..<len).compactMap{ _ in pswdChars.randomElement() })

    self.passwordTextField.text = rndPswd
}
```

If the user local is Korean "ko"  the password generated would be available on their keypad so it can be reproduced. The same goes for all languages.

[image: ko key]
[image: ko key 2]
[image: en key]

```
    let locale = NSLocale.current.languageCode
    let english = // Same as the local keys available
    let korean = // Same as the local keys available
    var textString = ""


    if locale == "en" {
        textString = english 
    }else if locale == "ko" {
        textString = korean 
    }
```

Comment: What do you believe you mean by "keyboard language" here? For example, you've marked "English" as a keyboard that includes $, but doesn't include € or £. All of those can be typed on a Mac keyboard, even in the US Locale, but some require Option, while in other Locales they don't. Which are part of the "keyboard language?" For Korean, on the 2-Set keyboard, ㅆ is "on the keyboard" as Shift-ㅅ. Is that a letter for your purposes? If you mean "letters in the language's alphabet," how do you expect to handle Chinese? (Also $ isn't in the English alphabet.)

Comment: You didn't tag this iOS, but assuming you only care about iOS keyboards, it's not any simpler there, though some of the issues are slightly different. For example, do you consider the Pinyin-QWERTY keyboard the "Chinese" keyboard, or the 10-key? Is `^_^` something you want in your set (that's a dedicated key on some iOS Chinese keyboards)?

Comment: If a user of a mobile device taps the button Generate Password the characters that are generated are available on their keypad or number pad to where they can reproduce the password.

Comment: As part of your question, I suggest sketching out a few examples of the characters you mean for a few languages. For example, the standard English keyboard on iOS can type many more characters than in your list. How did you select those characters? Korean is a decent second example, but of course Chinese will likely be the one to really nail down what you mean. There are 1000s of characters that can be typed on a Chinese keyboard. But Chinese keyboards on iOS do not have 1000s of keys. Showing the list for Korean and Chinese would illuminate your question.

Comment: In Settings>General>Keyboards>Keyboards, you can add many different keyboards in iOS without having to change your locale. This is an excellent way to explore what these keyboards look like, and the many options that exist for some languages.

Comment: I do not believe there is a function on iOS keyboards to return every keycap that exists (and some keyboards don't have keycaps such as the handwriting keyboards), so if that's the goal you probably cannot solve it. The keycaps on the Pinyin-10 keyboard have values like "ABC" and "DEF", so even keycaps isn't going to give you particularly useful information.

Comment: You may want to consider focusing on [character sets](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscharacterset) instead of localization which would have ranges of characters that could be used to generate random strings

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath CharacterSet isn't enumerable, so you can't easily pick a character out of it. Also, many characters in a given set are very difficult or impossible to type on most keyboards (which I think is the key goal of this question). For example, `CharacterSet.letters.contains("ㅓ") == true`. But you wouldn't want ㅓ as part of your password if you're typing on an English keyboard.

Comment: Getting what local keys (letters) are available may not be passable.

Comment: Maybe there's a way I can extract the password from (textContentType = .password) without using a web address. But I no nothing about this API

Comment: I see the picture you gave of a couple of Korean keyboards, but my question is what is the complete list of Korean characters you expect to get back from this function? Your examples are very inconsistent. `a` is easy to type on a Korean-10 keyboard, but it seems you don't want it. `{` is difficult to type on the US-English keyboard, but possible; should it be included? Your criteria seems ad hoc, and I don't see how it can be applied to Chinese.

Comment: Maybe it's simpler to say that my app is in 30 languages in 10 countries and I would like my user to be able to tap the Generate Password on the top of the keyboard and then be able to retype that password in a website or where they needed.

Comment: I suspected that was your goal. I expect that this will require by-hand localization based on an understanding of what makes sense in each of those languages (and particularly on keyboards people use). I don't think there's any way to automate that understanding of human interaction with your product. It's why Apple has so many very different keyboards. They don't just slap different alphabets on the QWERTY layout. Humans aren't that simple.

Comment: As an important example, Chinese characters generally take several taps to generate, so a 15 character password in Chinese is enormous compared to English, and represents much, much more entropy. You will likely want to adjust your lengths for some languages, and this isn't something that an algorithm can do for you. It's part of UX design.

Comment: Thanks Rob maybe time to rethink.